# Pyspark - Union two data frames with same column based n same id

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

DF1

| Id | Name | Desc | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Name1 | desc1 | etc1 |
| B | name2 | desc2 | etc2 |

DF2

| Id | Name | Desc | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Name2 | desc2 | etc2 |
| C | name2 | desc2 | etc2 |

I want to union records from DF2 into DF1 where the ID is equal and include all records from DF1.

Result DF

| Id | Name | Desc | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Name1 | desc1 | etc1 |
| B | name2 | desc2 | etc2 |
| A | name2 | desc2 | etc2 |

What is the best way to do it? Any help Is appreciated.

Comment: just filter `df2` for ids that are present in `df1` and then append the dataframes.

Comment: Is it more effective to have join or filter?

Comment: Can you provide a code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by doing a [semi join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html) keeping only the ids in df2 which exists in df1, followed by a [union](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union.html) with df1.

```
d1 = [
    ('A', 'Name1', 'desc1', 'etc1'),
    ('B', 'name2', 'desc2', 'etc2'),
  ]

d2 = [
    ('A', 'Name2', 'desc2', 'etc2'),
    ('C', 'name2', 'desc2', 'etc2'),
]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(d1, ['Id', 'Name', 'Desc', 'etc'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(d2, ['Id', 'Name', 'Desc', 'etc'])

df2.join(df1, on='Id', how='semi').union(df1).show()

+---+-----+-----+----+
| Id| Name| Desc| etc|
+---+-----+-----+----+
|  A|Name2|desc2|etc2|
|  A|Name1|desc1|etc1|
|  B|name2|desc2|etc2|
+---+-----+-----+----+
```